# C++ in Visual Studio Code on MacOS - std::make_unique

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, c++17, c++20

I'm running MacOS 10.15 and after many months of rebooting to my BootCamp Win10 with Visual Studio 2019 I decided to try out VS Code with C++ and Code Runner extension. Sadly, I pretty quickly got into troubles with outdated version of C++ that's built in OS (or downloaded with developer tools, I don't know).

I'm trying to run just simple `std::make_unique<T>` but all I get as a response is

```
error: no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'
```

This is my code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


class Pole{

    Pole(size_t chunk=100): chunk_(chunk), count_(0) {}

    public:
        void push_back(int item){

            if(count_ % chunk_ == 0){
                v_.push_back(std::make_unique< int[]>(chunk_));  //this is the problematic line

            }
            count_++;
            v_[count_/chunk_][count_%chunk_]=item;
        }



    private:
        size_t chunk_;
        size_t count_;

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int[]> > v_;

};
```

I already tried playing with `"cppStandard":` in `c_cpp_properties.json` and setting its value to `"cppStandard": "c++20"`, but it did not help.

Thank you!

Comment: Just checking: do you have `#include <memory>` somewhere?

Comment: @NicholasM Yeah, forgot to mention, it's of course included :-/

Comment: Make sure that the request for C++14 or newer Standard is making it to the command line.

Comment: @user4581301 Well that seems like the issue. Clang for Mac doesn't seem to support C++14 and I can't find substitute for Clang that would work.. Tried G++-9 from installed via Homebrew but doesn't work when compiling and throws some weird error (using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnkySV0sZmU as reference)

Comment: Clang for MacOS supports C++17.. `sudo xcode-select --reset && sudo xcode-select --install` to install dev tools. Then do `-DCLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=C++17` and `-DCLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++` or `-std=c++17`

Comment: Copy paste the bash script from: https://pastebin.com/raw/3uu6xKrA into a terminal and see if your clang runs it. If it prints `Hello World: 2 3` then it's a problem with your configuration/setup of Visual Studio Code somewhere.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, this does work, thank you. But I don't honestly see anything wrong with setup of Visual Studio Code. I switched "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++", "cppStandard": "c++20", "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64". But even with all those changes Output in VSCode still looks the same (the same error)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Visual Studio Code.
2. Open your project's folder.
3. Replace the `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` compiler path and properties below with:

-

```
"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
"cStandard": "c11",
"cppStandard": "c++17"
```

So that it kinda looks similar to:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++20"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Next open `./vscode/tasks.json` and for `command` and `args`, specify:

```
"command": "clang++",
"args": [
    "-std=c++17",
    "-stdlib=libc++",
    "${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp",
    "-o",
    "${workspaceFolder}/main.out",
    "--debug"
]
```

The two important args are:

```
"-std=c++17",
"-stdlib=libc++"
```

The rest you can leave how you have it..

Now in you should be able to build for C++17. Hit `Command + Shift + B` to build and `F5` or `Fn + F5` to run/debug.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't post my answer directly to this because of  lenght of those json files, it's above this.

Comment: Make sure the configuration files are actually in a `.vscode` folder which is located at the root of your project directory.

Comment: Just to recap, because my previous post was deleted - yes, all those .json config files are located in the .vscode folder since the the first try. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your code in the console. Maybe your VSCode is ill-configured. I had similar issues..
Anyway try compiling the code with:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 foo.cpp -o foo
```

This will give you warnings if needed and compiled with the C++17 standard.

Comment: Hi, yes, this works perfectly. Sadly even with this exact setup in `tasks.json` it doesn't work in VSCode :-/.

Comment: I'm a fan of VSCode, sadly I find it challenging to get everything to work on MacOS.. Although Atom imo is not a pretty as VSCode, but at least it works good with clang.